# Ms Word - Custom Border Art

Tags: ms-word, border, border-layout

I am trying to find a way to add custom page borders to ms word, so that I can access them from the Art: drop down menu.

[image]

I am using both watermarks, background images and borders and I would much prefer to keep them separate from each other.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, Microsoft protects its Office assets in locations not accessed by users. If they have designed a type of artwork that can be augmented by the user, the user-saved content will be saved to a completely different location, so the Office assets remain distinct.

Locations often vary in current versions of Office, but for 64-bit Office 2019, I find the Microsoft page border art at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\BORDERS. Each .BDR file contains several page borders, so MSART1.BDR contains the Birds in Flight, Party Favor, Apples, Heart Balloon, Skyrocket, Party Glass, Confetti Streamers and Flowers...Roses borders.

It would be difficult to reverse engineer the .BDR file format, and even if you did, there's no guarantee that Office would recognize a new .BDR file added to the folder.

It would be much easier to create custom borders, watermarks and background images, then add those to Building Blocks/AutoText, which is Microsoft's solution for user asset storage.

Comment: Thank you! I'll be looking into it further, but I believe that's the information I'll need for now ^^